# Java - Jboss deployment errors

Tags: java, jboss, security

I'm having problems with a project deployment. Here's the error i get:

```
01:08:26,780 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/domain-as]] (MSC service thread 1-7) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class pt.ist.anacom.applicationserver.ApplicationServerInitListener: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/x509/X509CertImpl
at pt.ist.anacom.applicationserver.ApplicationServerInitListener.generateCert(ApplicationServerInitListener.java:86) [classes:]
at pt.ist.anacom.applicationserver.ApplicationServerInitListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationServerInitListener.java:51) [classes:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3368) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_30]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl from [Module "deployment.domain-as.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103)
... 10 more
```

This happened when i added a new function to my code in which i call a function of another class to generate a security certificate. This is the code of the function that makes the call:

```
    public static void generateCert(String name, KeyPair key, int days, String algorithm) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException{

    System.out.println("Starting to generate certificate");
    X509Certificate cert = CertificationAuthority.generateCertificate(name, key, days, algorithm);
    //return cert;
}
```

It does make the print, but then the error occurs. The generate certificate is in another class (the CertificationAuthority class) and has the following code:

```
 public static X509Certificate generateCertificate(String dn, KeyPair pair, int days, String algorithm)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
        {

    PrivateKey privkey = pair.getPrivate();
    X509CertInfo info = new X509CertInfo();

    //caso haja tempo, tratar isto com long + long
    Date from = new Date();
    Date to = new Date(from.getTime() + days * 864000001);
    CertificateValidity interval = new CertificateValidity(from, to);
    BigInteger sn = new BigInteger(64, new SecureRandom());
    X500Name owner = new X500Name(dn);

    info.set(X509CertInfo.VALIDITY, interval);
    info.set(X509CertInfo.SERIAL_NUMBER, new CertificateSerialNumber(sn));
    info.set(X509CertInfo.SUBJECT, new CertificateSubjectName(owner));
    info.set(X509CertInfo.ISSUER, new CertificateIssuerName(owner));
    info.set(X509CertInfo.KEY, new CertificateX509Key(pair.getPublic()));
    info.set(X509CertInfo.VERSION, new CertificateVersion(CertificateVersion.V3));
    AlgorithmId algo = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.md5WithRSAEncryption_oid);
    info.set(X509CertInfo.ALGORITHM_ID, new CertificateAlgorithmId(algo));

    // Sign the cert to identify the algorithm that's used.
    X509CertImpl cert = new X509CertImpl(info);
    cert.sign(privkey, algorithm);

    // Update the algorithm, and resign.
    algo = (AlgorithmId)cert.get(X509CertImpl.SIG_ALG);
    info.set(CertificateAlgorithmId.NAME + "." + CertificateAlgorithmId.ALGORITHM, algo);
    cert = new X509CertImpl(info);
    cert.sign(privkey, algorithm);

    certificates.add(cert);

    return cert;
        }
```

I don't understand why i'm getting that error. I'm trying to test the functionality of the generateCertificate methdod but i'm not being able to do it because of this error.

Anyone has an idea of what is happening?

Comment: you're missing a class, see this error `sun/security/x509/X509CertImpl`

Comment: I'm using eclipse with jboss plugins to develop and deploy.

Comment: `sun/security/x509/X509CertImpl` is supposed to be in rt.jar.  Are you using a Sun JVM, or some other implementation?  If it's not Sun's JVM then there's likely some leakage of a Sun security configuration into the non-Sun environment.

Comment: Any idea on how i can solve the problem ? I'm using using eclipse with the latest java plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss isolates Sun classes away. Have a look at the `sun.jdk` module, you need to add `sun/security/x509` as an export there or create your own module that does this.

Comment: I had to add  <path name="sun/security/x509"/> to the module.xml file in /modules/sun/jdk/main in the jboss directory.